# Prove certain sets are 2-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, 3d, surfaces, geometric-topology

I've been solving problems from my Topology course, and still don't get clear how to prove certain sets are $n$-manifolds when it's not very obvious how to pick the neighbourhoods. Consider the following exercise I'm trying:

> Consider the following sets: $$M_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 \mid
>  x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1\}$$ $$M_{-1}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 \mid
>  x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2=1\}$$ $$M=M_1\cup M_{-1}\phantom{a}, \phantom{aa}
>  N=M\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$$ Determine which of them are 2-manifolds,
> which are surfaces and which are compact surfaces.

Of course the topological space where those sets live is $\mathbb R^3$ with the Euclidean topology.

At first, I already know in my mind how those sets are, clearly $M_1$ and $M_{-1}$ are spheres whith just the coordinates origin in common, and the form of $M$ and $N$ is deduced from that. So from that information I in fact have spoiled me that both $M_1$ and $M_{-1}$ are compact surfaces.

For $N$, I intuitively see (correct me if I'm wrong) that it's 2-manifold, but it's not surface (hence not compact surface) because it's not connected.

For $M$, I think isn't even a 2-manifold, since $(0,0,0)$ don't has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to a 2-dimensional euclidean ball.

So I can intuitively see the properties of the subspaces, but my problem is rigurously proving it. How can I prove, for example, that any point of $M_1$ has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to a 2-dimensional euclidean ball? How can I prove $(0,0,0)$ hasn't it in $M$?

Comment: For example, suppose that $(0,0,0)$ had a neighborhood $U$ in $M$ which is homeomorphic to an open subset of the plane. Then we can shrink such a set $U$ in $M$ to be homeomorphic to a ball. However consider $U\setminus \{ (0,0,0) \}$, which is a disconnected open subset of $M$, and is supposed to be homeomorphic to a punctured ball which is connected. Since homeomorphisms take connected sets to connected sets, this would be a contradiction…

In order to prove the other sets are manifolds, express them locally as the graph of some continuous (or smooth) functions.

Comment: To prove that $M_1$ is a manifold use latitude and longitude to map a neighborhood to $\mathbb R^2$. This would not work at the poles, but you can choose where the poles are depending on the neighborhood.